# Using Complementary slackness THM to check optimal solution for dual

Tags: duality-theorems

I Have the following LP :

> $\mathcal Min$ $z= 8x_1+4x_2+3x_3$
>
> s.t.
>
> $\mathcal 2x_1-x_2+x_3+x_4$ $\geq 1$ ($y_1$)
>
> $\mathcal x_1+x_2-x_4$ $\geq 2$  ($y_2$)
>
> $x_1$->$x_4$ $\geq 0$

I wrote the Dual for this problem and it's as follow :

> $\mathcal Max$ $z=$ $y_1 +2y_2$
>
> s.t.
>
> $2y_1 + y_2 \leq 8$
>
> $-y_1 + y_2 \leq 4$
>
> $y_1 \leq 3$
>
> $y_1 - y_2 \leq 0$

My question here is : Using the theorem of complementary slackness I want to demonstrate that $y_1 = 4/3$ & $y_2 = 16/3$ are optimal solutions for the dual problem.